# Sql multiple columns to retrieve a single value

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

```
id Mobile   Home      Business
1  07707    0161      abcdefg
2  Null   07798567     Null
3  07709  078 iju      Null
```

Hi. I am trying to figure out how to retrieve a mobile number from a table which has some bad data in it.

The number can be in any of the columns which are all varchars.
The number to be sought has to be starting with 07 and must be 11 digits long.

So far I have only managed this :

```
select REPLACE ( 
      COALESCE (Business_Phone, Cell_Phone, Home_Phone) Contact_Phone 
               , ' '.'') 
from testtable
where len () =11?
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN REPLACE(Business_Phone, ' ', '') LIKE '07[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN REPLACE(Business_Phone, ' ', '')
        WHEN REPLACE(Cell_Phone, ' ', '') LIKE '07[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN REPLACE(Cell_Phone, ' ', '')
        WHEN REPLACE(Home_Phone, ' ', '') LIKE '07[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN REPLACE(Home_Phone, ' ', '')
        END AS TrueMobile
    FROM testtable
) x
WHERE x.TrueMobile IS NOT NULL
```

It tries to find a field that contains 11 digits (the first two being 07), any number of spaces in between, and no other characters. It first tries `Business_Phone`, then `Cell_Phone`, then `Home_Phone`. Records where none of these 3 fields match, are excluded from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (id INT, Mobile VARCHAR(20), Home VARCHAR(20),Business VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1,'07707'      ,    '0161'  , 'abcdefg'),
(2,Null         ,  '07798567',     Null),
(3,'07709'      ,  '078 iju' ,  '07709175555'),
(4,'07709178921',  '078 iju' ,     Null)
```

### Query

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @TABLE 
     UNPIVOT (Numbers FOR Num_Types IN (Mobile,Home,Business)) up
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE C1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM CTE C2
                 WHERE LEFT(C2.Numbers, 2) = '07'
                 AND C2.Numbers NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
                 AND C1.id = C2.id
                 AND C1.Numbers = C2.Numbers
                 AND C1.Num_Types = C2.Num_Types)
```

### Result

```
╔════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ Numbers ║ Num_Types ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ 0161    ║ Home      ║
║  1 ║ abcdefg ║ Business  ║
║  3 ║ 078 iju ║ Home      ║
║  4 ║ 078 iju ║ Home      ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks. But sadly my skill set is not refined enough  to even understand what just happened here :(